# sed - regex address range is matching lines outside the range when N command is used

Tags: sed, text-processing

**Problem Description:**

> Consider the below XML file:
>
> ```
> <xmlhead1>
>    <xmlsubhead1>
>        <record>
>            <field>Hello</field>
>            <field>World</field>
>        </record>
>        <record>
>            <field>DELETEKEY</field>
>            <field>World1</field>
>        </record>
>    </xmlsubhead1>
> </xmlhead1>
> ```
>
> My objective is to remove a "record" XML tag, when the field sub tag
>   of that XML node contains DELETEKEY as the value.
>
> So in the above XML file i will remove
>
> ```
>    <record>
>        <field>DELETEKEY</field>
>        <field>World1</field>
>    </record>
> ```

**Solution Chosen:**
I tried to use **GNU sed** to solve the above problem:
Below is my code.

```
sed -n '

/<xmlhead1>/,/<\/xmlhead1>/{
    /<xmlsubhead1>/,/<\/xmlsubhead1>/{
        /<record>/,/<\/record>/{

            #Append to hold space
            H

            #if match DELETEKEY, start delete processing for the xml <record> element
            /<field>DELETEKEY<\/field>/{
                s/.*//g ; x
                b delete
            }

            #if you have reached the end tag of the <record> element,
            #print the hold space and clear the buffers
            /<\/record>/{
                g ; s/^\n//g; p
                s/.*//g ; x ; s/.*//g
            }

            #continue to next line
            b

            #delete processing
            :delete
            {
                #clear pattern space.
                s/.*//g

                #Read Next Line and remove new line(\n)
                N
                s/^\n//g

                #end delete processing when line matches the end tag </record>
                /<\/record>/b

                #else continue to get next line for delete process
                b delete
            }
        }
    }
}

#print all other lines
p

' $inputfile
```

> *The logic is as below:*
>
> 1. Match Address Range beginning with `<xmlhead1> and ending with
>      </xmlhead1>`
> 2. Match Inner Address Range beginning with
>      `<xmlsubhead1> and ending with </xmlsubhead1>`
> 3. Match Inner Address Range `<record> to </record>`
> 4. When inside `<record>` tag,
>          (i) append all the lines to Hold space.
>          (ii) if the line matches `DELETEKEY`, then this record has to be deleted.Do step iii and iv. Else if no matches, go to step v
>          (iii) For delete, clear the hold space and jump to the delete branch
>          (iv) In the delete branch, read all the next lines using 'N' command till `</record>` is encountered. When `</record>` is
>      encountered, exit out of the loop and start processing the next
>      line.
>          (v) When not processing delete logic, if `</record>` is encountered, it means a block of `<record> to </record>` is
>      successfully processed and is present in the hold space.
>          (vi) so take it out of hold space and print it.

**Output of the above logic:**

```
<xmlhead1>
   <xmlsubhead1>
       <record>
           <field>Hello</field>
           <field>World</field>
       </record>
</xmlhead1>
```

**Problem in the output:**
You can notice that the record element with the DELETEKEY is removed, but the `</xmlsubhead1>` tag is missing in the output.

**Issue Debugging:**
On debugging i found that after encountering a `</record>` line in the delete processing, inside the `<record> to </record>` range, the inner address range match should have ended since i have read and processed the `</record>` line.

But the `<record> to </record>` range block seems to process the `</xmlsubhead1>` line too.

I found this by adding the below code inside the command block of `<record>` range.

```
/<record>/,/<\/record>/{

    /<\/recordList>/{
        s/.*/record list is inside the record to record range/g
        p
    }
```

Can someone explain this behavior of sed, that a range match is exceeding the actual match ? In this case `<record> to </record> range match is also matching </xmlsubhead1>`

Comment: Is there a reason you are using regex instead of a properly XML-aware tool like `xmlstarlet`?

Comment: No reasons. i just wanted to implement in sed and stumbled upon the above behavior. Seems strange. Though later on i will be using other tools to actually solve the problem, i wanted to know why sed seems to behave as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sed to edit XML, use an XML-aware tool. For example, in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can write:

```
open file.xml ;
delete //record[field="DELETEKEY"] ;
save :b ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion , but i'm curious to know why sed is behaving so.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments about using a proper XML parser.

The issue with your sed script, is that you read (`N`) lines in your `:delete` "function".  Here is a working example that uses a simpler logic:

```sed
/<xmlhead1>/,/<\/xmlhead1>/{
  /<xmlsubhead1>/,/<\/xmlsubhead1>/{
    /<record>/ {
      :a
      N
      /<\/record>/!ba
      /<field>DELETEKEY<\/field>/d
    }
  }
}
p
```

I.e. when in the right context, read a full record (assuming simplified XML structure), if the record contains the offending text, delete it.

Comment: " The issue with your sed script, is that you read (N) lines in your :delete "function" " , Can you please elaborate why this is a problem ?

Comment: @Abis: The issue seems to be that you read the `</record>` line with `N` and thus the `/<record>/,/<\/record>/` range is never terminated. I think